# Wordpress gallery page with title AND descriptions?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to create a page template for wordpress that will allow a user to upload images onto the page easily, like the native upload I suppose. Then be able to render the images on the page like this picture shows. Simple 3 columns, with image, then title and description under it. The images can just be static even, dont need to link or lightbox out.
Any thoughts on how I can do this?
Thank you.

[image]
<sub>(source: [skitch.com](http://img.skitch.com/20100723-dpkh5xf9x1mnfse176wxxd1cr2.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The [PhotoSmash plugin](http://smashly.net/photosmash-galleries/) does pretty much exactly what you want.